# Paypal Form Ruins My ASP.NET webforms layout -> How to Solve?

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, paypal-buttons

I am a student who is doing up a simple website in asp.net. My problem is, I wish to integrate Paypal on one of the pages, but asp.net has the <s>ridiculous</s> `<form runat="server">` that is getting in my way. I am building a simple site layout using blueprint css, a very basic three-column layout. However, I need my main content section to be able to use the paypal form (buy now button), and the other areas of the site to use user controls, which I presume requires them to be wrapped in that irritating form tag. In fact, I would like to have a sitemap path control at the top of the main section of the site: something very basic. How might I achieve that? My problem is: I can't put the Paypal button in the form, and I don't know how to shift a 4th div into place. I am not even sure how divs and forms stack on each other.

Could I have some help please?

The page with the problem is: http://clubofpep.org/sandbox/sandbox_Alumni.aspx.

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to popular belief, you *can* have more than one form on ASP.Net webforms pages.  What you cannot do is have more than one form with runat="server", nest a second form inside ASP.Net's main form, or use asp.net server controls outside the main form.

Therefore, to integrate a separate paypal form with the rest of an asp.net webforms page, you have to make sure that you can put it either before or after *all* of the asp.net web controls on the page, and then edit the aspx markup to make sure your paypal form is completely outside of asp.net's form.

The other thing is that a quick web search shows a multitude of paypal controls written for asp.net that will work with the required asp.net form to submit the payment. You could always try one of those.

Comment: I was wondering if the <form> tag was treated as a separate div, because I having some problems with styling. Also, I don't seem to find the "multitude of paypal controls". What I find mostly is 2. The "free" control from ComponentOne which requires a PayPal Business Account, and the not-so-cheap ASP.Net Paypal Button control. You know of any others?

Comment: @Raphael - A form tag is a block level element, just like any other block level element. So, yes, it's kind of like another div tag. A google for `asp.net paypal control` returns results for me with at least 4 _different_ controls on the first page.

Comment: @Joel, excellent explanation. I'm posting another alternative I came across - creating a custom HtmlForm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace CustomForm
{
    public class GhostForm : System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
    {
        protected bool _render;

        public bool RenderFormTag
        {
            get { return _render; }
            set { _render = value; }
        }

        public GhostForm()
        {
            //By default, show the form tag
            _render = true;
        }

        protected override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            //Only render the tag when _render is set to true
            if (_render)
                base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
        }

        protected override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            //Only render the tag when _render is set to true
            if (_render)
                base.RenderEndTag(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

ASPX:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CF" Namespace="CustomForm" Assembly="CustomForm" %>
<body>
    <CF:GhostForm id="mainForm" runat="server">
    ...
</body>

<img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"> <asp:Button ID="checkoutBtn" runat="server" OnClick="CheckButton_Click"
    Text="Checkout" Width="100" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // Workaround for PayPal form problem
    GhostForm mainForm = new GhostForm();
    mainForm.RenderFormTag = false;
    // Go ahead and submit to PayPal :)
}
```