# Can we use multiple forms in a web page?

Tags: asp.net, forms

So far, all the web pages I met contain at most one `<form>` tag. Why not multiple ones? I can not think of reasons why multiple forms can't coexist within the same web page.

Also, to be specific to ASP.NET - why are all the server controls are placed within the `<form>` tag? Why not place them somewhere else?

Plus,

I noticed that in an `.aspx` file, the `<form>` tag has the *runat=server* attribute, while a normal server control such as `Button` also has one. So it seems the `<form>` is also a **server control**. But strangely enough, I cannot find it in the Visual Studio Toolbox.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There can be multiple forms, [with](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/) [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91350/multiple-forms-on-asp-net-page/91374#91374).

It is indeed a [shortcoming](http://www.mknopf.com/articles/aspnet-web-form-disadvantages.html) of WebForms. In ASP.NET MVC you can implement as many forms as you want (and it is valid & correct behavior of web pages).

The reason all server controls are placed inside `<form>` tag is to allow the WebForms engine to recognize them, load their values & save their values from/to the ViewState. Almost all infrastructure of control management in WebForms is based on the idea that a  tag contains everything you access from the code-behind.

Comment: If it is such an obvious shortcoming, why the ASP.NET guy still designed it this way? Any special considerration? Or compromise?

Comment: When they designed ASP.NET, it was a totally different world of web and assumptions. No Ajax, unawareness to bandwidth (thus everything is serialized via the ViewState which can grow extremely large). MS tried to bring the model of VB forms to the web - everything is drag&drop onto a form, and the controls "magically" remember what their value was before submit. All that requires a managed form element container.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out, this is one of the shortcomings of WebForms.  I do want to point out, additionally, that with [cross-page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) and [validation groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx), you can typically reach your desired behavior (for *most* "multi-form" solutions).

Comment: An alternative to validation groups would be to add the `formnovalidate` property to a button that does not need to be restricted by required fields.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the additional question: the `<form runat="server">` is parsed as `HtmlForm` class behind the scenes, which inherits from `HtmlControl` like any other HTML element with `runat="server"`.

Unlike any other HtmlControl though, there can exist only one instance per page and it does not appear in the toolbox as it's added automatically to every new Form you create, so it's quite pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done - by creating a custom HtmlForm object and toggling the forms as needed. I've just answered a similar question here (with code):

[Paypal Form Ruins My ASP.NET webforms layout -> How to Solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419519/paypal-form-ruins-my-asp-net-webforms-layout-how-to-solve/7518476#7518476)

Answer (score 0):

many non server forms - you can , but only one runAt Server form

i also found this :

A server-side form tag is the tag which has a runat="server" attribute. If this attribute
is missing, then it's a typical HTML form tag. The conclusion is that you are allowed to use 
multiple form tags on a page, as long as only one has the runat="server" attribute. The 
disadvantage of the form that doesn't have this attribute, is that **view state** won't work
 (meaning form values will disappear when using the back/forward browser buttons). It's a 
small price to pay if you really need multiple forms on a page.

Comment: One of the major concepts in ASP.NET (WebForms) is that the entire site is contained within a single form. Whenever a postback is performed, every input on the page is posted. The reason for this is because of ViewState, a hidden form field in ASP.NET WebForms which contains all the state information for every control on the page. This viewstate input needs to be posted on every single postback in order for all the state of the controls to be reloaded properly

Comment: @smwikipedia, See my answer above.

Answer (score -5):

1. Take  master page  & set  design.
2. Take  one  form in master page.
3. Second  form   take  in contain place holder.
4. In contain place holder in only for  write form tag (not use)
5. Add aspx  page  &  design second form but not write  form tag only for  control  put
6. Take button  click event fire code  write

This is proper  way of   two  form

Comment: I'm sorry I don't normally downvote for bad english, but this is really incoherent.  It may even be a correct answer, but it's impossible to tell.