# 2 contact forms on the same page sending to different emails

Tags: forms, contacts, newsletter

Hi and thanks for looking.

Can you have 2 forms on the same webpage? I have a php script handy, and the fields would be re-used.

Form 1 would be a contact form with name, email, subject and message.

Form 2 would be a newsletter opt-in with name and email (I would add the user's email manually to my newsletter manager)

Would they process if on the same page? Each form would go to a different email address, ie, form 1 would go to info@mydomain.com and form 2 would be sent to signup@mydomain.com

Comment: Have you tried to [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search)?

Comment: I'm currently looking at threads but the OPs have complicated questions that I don't understand. My needs are much more basic. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I might add that I'm using PHP and not ASP, but here is a link to anyone that lands here and is using ASP in their server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page

Comment: Just use two different forms. Have you even TRIED? Sharing the form input elements won't work unless you use some client-side scripting.

Comment: Thanks for looking Hugo. I've added a solution below.

Comment: you may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page, it has other options too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing Multiple Forms on One Page with PHP: http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/

Examples:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
blah blah blah
</form>


<form name="mailinglist" method="post" action="join.php">
blah blah blah
</form>
```