# How to place two forms on the same page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to place both register and login form on the same page.
They both starts with:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) ...
```

so, I need something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST_01))...  // regForm
  and 
if (!empty($_POST_02))...  //loginForm
```

Also how to prevent executing first form if the second is busy, and vice versa (user clicks on both)
My idea is to create a simple variable on starting process, for example `$x = 1` and at the end of process `$x = 0`, so:

```
if ((!empty($_POST_01)) And $x = 0)...
```

Probably, there is a better way.

Comment: So your question is not how to put two HTML form elements on the same page, but how to process the requests originating from submitting different forms with the same PHP pgae, isn't it?

Comment: @ppeterka, yes, that's it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could make two forms with 2 different actions

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<br />

<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Or do this

```
<form action="doStuff.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<br />

<form action="doStuff.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Then you PHP file would work as a switch($_POST['action']) ... furthermore, they can't click on both links at the same time or make a simultaneous request, each submit is a separate request.

Your PHP would then go on with the switch logic or have different php files doing a login procedure then a registration procedure

Comment: A bit better description on why he'd need to do so would be good, but otherwise +1

Comment: cristi_b, I have idea know. Thanks. I think - solved. BTW reasons is - consistent design.

Comment: you can implement my version or what Neal proposed, a form with 2 submit buttons (register and login)

Comment: @cristi_b, interesting idea. Maybe I'll try.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

Well you can have each form go to to a **different** page. (which is preferable)

Or have a different value for the a certain input and base posts on that:

```
switch($_POST['submit']) {
    case 'login': 
    //...
    break;
    case 'register':
    //...
    break;
}
```

Comment: yeah, same page, different submit buttons with different values on the same form ... a bit better than my solution

Comment: i noticed here, when an answer appears on the screen, it comes already `-1` votted !!?

Comment: you forgot to mention to add a hidden input

Answer (score 6):

Give the submit buttons for both forms different names and use PHP to check which button has submitted data.

Form one button - btn1
Form two button -btn2

PHP Code:

```
if($_POST['btn1']){
    //Login
}elseif($_POST['btn2']){
    //Register
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this easiest method.

```html
<form action="validator.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" form="form1">
</form>

<br />

<form action="validator.php" method="post" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" form="form2">
</form>
```

Comment: very easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two form with two submit button:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
  <input type="submit" name="btnPostMe1" value="Confirm"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="page.php">
  <input type="submit" name="btnPostMe2" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```

And here is your PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnPostMe1'])) { //your code 1 }
if (isset($_POST['btnPostMe2'])) { //your code 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. Assumed that login form has: username and password inputs.

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != "" && isset($_POST['password']) && trim($_POST['password']) != ""){
//login
} else {
//register
}
```

Comment: And what if the register form does have username and password fields too? I think a registration form _does_ usually have those...

Comment: @ppeterka, yes, both forms have username and pass fields

Comment: I know it's not good to assume, but he doesn't provide much info so, I thought that he has one form with two divs(login, register) and when he clicks submit he must check the post data. It's not a good idea to operate this way, but let's hope that I my simple code was usefull for him.

Comment: he have to put different names if he want to do the way he expressed. For example in register form changes names: new_username, new_password, confirmed_password.