# How to set PHP session in onclick event HTML without POST/ GET/FORM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I have a problem with my work. There is a repetition for button and value based on database. I want to set PHP session when button HTML get clicked for identification which one value and button in repetition is clicked.But it's impossible to used FORM/POST/GET. because FORM tag already used for another need which is used in the same page. So it can't used FORM/POST/GET twice, right?

Here's my Code

```
<?php
while($result=pg_fetch_row($call)){
    echo
            "<tr>
            <td  align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[0]</td>
            <td align=\"center\"  class=\"form\">$result[1]</td>
            <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[2]</td>
            <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[3]</td>
            <td  class=\"form\" width=\"2%\">
                  <a id=\"selector\" href=\"#\"><img width=\"120%\"height=\"130%\" src=\"../img/view.png\"/></a>
            </td>
            </tr>\n";
  }
?>
```

The button in Code

```
<td  class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"> <a id=\"selector\" href=\"#\"><img  width=\"120%\"height=\"130%\" src=\"../img/view.png\"/></a>
</td>
```

I want to set PHP session to catch it in another page which is the another page would be a popup page in this current page.

What am i supposed to do? Thankyou in Advanced. if you don't understand, let me know. :D

Comment: You can check here - [Two forms one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page)

Comment: @inf1ux is it okay to used two form in one page? are there any side effects or the disadvantages?

Comment: You will have to use a different action for each form.

Comment: @inf1ux Ok thankyou for you comment. I'll try it.

Comment: @inf1ux It doesn't work because another page will be a popup page in current page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.