# Laravel, how to get all value from different form in a same page?

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see the code below, I have 2 forms in a same page. How to I to pass all the value('getfur' and 'customer') to controller after I press the submit button in the second form? This is only a snippet of my codes.

I already tried this in controller like this below, but it return null

```
$getAllInput = $request->all();
dump($getAllInput );  //return null
```

**view**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Furniture</label>
        {!!  Form::select('getfur',$getFuniture, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Select Furniture---']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}




{!! Form::open(['route'=>['fur.store','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        {!!  Form::text('customer', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**EDIT (FULL CODE)**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Furniture</label>
        {!!  Form::select('getfur',$getFuniture, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Select Furniture---']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}




{!! Form::open(['url'=>['fur/1','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        //some input form
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(['url'=>['fur/2','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        //some input form
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(['url'=>['fur/3','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        //some input form
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and so on...until the url reaches 'fur/20', i dont want the select form in each div

Comment: are you submiting the form through javascript ? otherwise you have to specify button type submit  `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>`

Comment: no, i did not use javascript

Comment: add that to the button and try dd to see what are u getting

Comment: if i may ask, how do i do that? i am not familiar with js

Comment: just  replace your button filed with mine `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>`

Comment: they share same action, so combine forms

Comment: No, 2 forms in 1 page are separate. They have told about it in :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi the dump() output with all kinds of stuff, i can only see 'customer' but not 'getfur'

Comment: If you want to get both value from 2 form in controller. Just combine it to 1 form

Comment: @MahdiYounesi bare in mind that this is snippet of my codes, there is a lot of different forms in my codes

Comment: @NgoTuan the answer to your question is same as MahdiYounesi

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to do it. Bind a listener "onClick" to the submit button and then get all values you need and send it to the server using jQuery.post() for example.

Comment: if i may ask, how do i do that? im not familiar with js

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two input of the two forms .  You don't need to open and close the two forms . Only opening and closing of one form will do the job .

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['fur.store','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Furniture</label>
    {!!  Form::select('getfur',$getFuniture, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Select Furniture---']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Customer</label>
{!!  Form::text('customer', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
<button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and in controller you can do like this

```
$getAllInput = $request->all();
dump($getAllInput );  //return null
```

Comment: this is only snippet of my codes, in my codes (same page) have many different forms

Comment: If you want to submit the thing to the same controller then you need to use the common form or the another difficult way would be using JavaScript to do such task . Those two are only the possible way to do so you need to do one of these

Comment: im not familiar with js, perhaps you can post it here?

Comment: Can you post the full source code of the view page then only I can help with that

Comment: i edited my question for your reference, i dont want the select form in each div

Comment: So on which one of the url action form /fur/1 to /fur/20  you want to do you want to dump all the data

Comment: it is depend on the user which he/she would like to submit on

Comment: So you want to combine the data from select form and and the form data for the form /fur/1 to /fur/20 right?

Comment: yes, i just wanted to get the selected value from the first form and the value from whichever form the user selected. i just dont want the select/dropdown form displayed in each div

Comment: Instead of creating 20 different forms for the each type of customer . Create a common form and add twenty different inputs  like   {!!  Form::text('fur_1', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!} {!!  Form::text('fur_2", null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!} and so on

Comment: as i said earlier(again), each div have different input forms...for example, div number 1 have text, comboboxes and datepicker, while div number 2 have only text, while div number 15 have combobox, checkbox, select box, text etc etc...i cannot mix them together

Answer (score 1):

So what you could do its grab the id's and submit them using javascript:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Furniture</label>
        {!!  Form::select('getfur',$getFuniture, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Select Furniture---','id'=>'myAppForm']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}




{!! Form::open(['route'=>['fur.store','id'=>'myAppForm1']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        {!!  Form::text('customer', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForms()" />
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then add javascript after html:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    submitForms = function(){
        document.getElementById("myAppForm").submit();
        document.getElementById("myAppForm1").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm, not sure why `$request->get('getfur');` return null

Comment: only 'customer' have its value

Comment: okay so the form its being subbmitted correctly. post the dd output how it looks. check $getFuniture if it has value otherwise it will fall back  to null @learnprogramming

Comment: obviously, the $getFuniture has its id and and its name, i already checked...the codes in the controller `$getFuniture = Furniture::where('status, 1)->pluck('fur_name', 'id');` ...the dd output displayed the 'customer' and other bunch of stuffs but not 'getfur'