# Submit button for second form submits first form on page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to include two forms on the same page. Below is much simpler than what I want to do, but it has the same error.

```html
<div class="content-form">

<form id="b_form" name="form_b" class="form" method="post"> 
</form>
    
<form id="a_form" name="form_a" class="form" method="post"> 
<input type="number" id="field_quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" />
<button type="submit" form="a_form" name="__action" value="new_shipment" class="btn btn-submit btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
```

The code snippet is actually a smarty template that gets included in a larger page. I think the issue is contained within this code though because the rest of the page has div tags, so it's not like I have a nested form.

**The issue:** When I click the submit button, I echo the $_POST object on the php page that handles the request. Even when the quantity field is filled in, I still get `{"__action":"new_shipment"}` as the contents of the $_POST.

If I swap the order of the two forms, then the $_POST does indeed contain the quantity field. Why does the submit button in the second form not submit the fields in the second? How do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if it'll solve the problem, but don't you need to specify the action attribute in the form?

Comment: @RafaelRozon yeah, I just added that to make sure. It doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

So, there are different ways to handle this. I went here http://phpfiddle.org, clicked on the Window tab, choose HTML Form and pasted your html and added some input on the first form:

```
<form id="b_form" name="form_b" class="form" method="post"> 
    <input type="number" id="field_quantity_b" name="quantity" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" form="b_form" name="form_b_btn" value="new_shipment" class="btn btn-submit btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="a_form" name="form_a" class="form" method="post"> 
    <input type="number" id="field_quantity_a" name="quantity" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" form="a_form" name="form_a_btn" value="new_shipment" class="btn btn-submit btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then I added this

```
<?php

    if($_POST && isset($_POST['form_b_btn'])) {
        echo "FORM B ";
        print_r($_POST);
    }

    if($_POST && isset($_POST['form_a_btn'])) {
        echo "FORM A ";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

You need different values for the name of your submit buttons. Then when you check the $_POST, you verify which form was submit. There are other methods, like specifying different actions and then having different files to handle them. This may help you: [How to place two forms on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page)