# How to merge two input that are in different forms

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have an index page that upload a file. An input button does the upload of the file and another import the grades to an external system. To import the grades, the user should be authenticated. Because of this, I have create two forms, and each button is in a form. However, it is not working because the first time that upload a grade and click import grades, it works just fine. The second time, when I click on "Upload file" button, it does the import grade at the same time. How I do to separate this actions, or better, add those two action in a same button?

I already tried to merge both forms by adding `action="authenticateUser.php"` to the first `form` and remove the second `form`, but it doesn't work.

```
<title>Import Grades Widget</title>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <labeL class="tool-actions"> <span>Choose CSV File:</span></labeL>

  <input class="tool-actions" type="file" accept="text/csv" id='uploadfile' name="userfile" />
  <p>
    <!--add space btw buttons -->
    <br>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="send" id="btnSend" value="Upload file" />

    <labeL class="tool-actions"> <span></span></labeL>
    <?php
       require_once "upload.php";                
     ?>
    <p id="info-message-crn" style="color:red"></p>
</form>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="authenticateUser.php" id="configForm">
  <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnImport" name="btnImport" value="Import Grades" />
  <?php 
  if(file_exists("uploads/uploadFile.csv") AND isset($_POST['btnImport'])) {  
      require_once ('apiCalls.php');  
  }else {
      ?>
  <p style="color:grey" id="info-message">
    <?php echo "Select a csv file.";?>
  </p>

  <?php
  }
  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to decide if you want to keep those actions separate or combine them into a single step. If you want to separate them, then you have a few options - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page. If you want to keep those 2 actions in a single step, then I'd use a single form called Upload and Process which'd be responsible for uploading and then processing the data directly after.

Comment: @waterloomatt how do I do to merge since I have an action in the second form? When I add the action (ie. authenticateUser.php) my upload do not work anymore.

Comment: Please help! I tried to separate since I have the authenticateUser.php as action in the second form, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Also, why don't you just set a different _action_ on each form? Have your upload form post its data to _upload.php_ and the process form post its data to _process.php_. Don't have any _include_ calls in the forms - it complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the way you layout your logic because it is currently a bit too complicated. Keep things very simple with 3 simple files.

- index.php - the main "display" file which only renders the forms. It does nothing else.
- upload.php - handles the upload portion and redirects back to index.php
- process.php - authenticates a user, processes any pending files, then redirects back to index.php

Notice that each form posts data to its own **handler** (*upload.php* and *process.php*). It does this with the *action* attribute of the form. That handler is responsible for the actual logic of either uploading or processing a pending file.

After the handler has finished its work, it redirects back to index.php which will render the upload form, and if appropriate, will also render the process form.

**index.php**

```
// Notice the actions on the forms. Each form sends data to its own handler
<form name="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    // Don't include any logic in here - only inputs and buttons.
    // All the upload logic is in upload.php
</form>

// Only show this form if there are pending files to process
// ** Side note - this could just be a link which points to process.php
// ** It does not need to be a form. 
if (exists (pending file(s) to process) {
    <form name="process" method="post" action="process.php">
        ...
        // Don't include any logic in here - only inputs and buttons.
        // All the processing logic is in process.php
    </form>
}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if (request method === POST) {
    upload file logic
}

redirect back to index.php
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
if (request method === POST) {
    authenticate user - if !authenticated > redirect to login
    process the file 
}

redirect back to index.php
```