# Form tag in html not working

Tags: asp.net

I am not a skilled programmer and I am building a site using a third party's CMS.  I have created a `<form>` in order to gather information and send it to an external site.  My code doesn't work.  The reason I am told is that the site is built on ASP.NET and as the 'master'page already has a `<form>` element in it and `<form>` elements cannot be embedded inside one another; so what I've written will never work.  I have been advised to look for a java based solution, but I'm at a loss.

My present code is pretty basic...

```
<form action="http://ExternalWebSite.com" method="post" id="subForm">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
    <label for="Email">Email Address:</label><br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <label for="Dog name">Your dog's name:</label><br /><input type="text" name="dogname" id="dogname" /><br />
    <label for="Town where you live">Town where you live:</label><br /><input type="text" name="town" id="town" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

How can I make this execute without using the  tag inside my html code?

Comment: If you are indeed using a master page, have you tried copying your form attributes to the one on the master and removing your form tags just to see if it will post for you?

Comment: The code you have posted is not .NET and it doesn't use a master page.  Is this the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET web forms adds one `<form runat="server">` in your application.  Therefore, you can't nest forms, but you can get multiple forms through a hack, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544462/231716).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call (post in this case) too to that url

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://ExternalWebSite.com",
      data: { name: $("#name").val(), $("#email").val(), $("#dogname").val(), $("#town").val() },
      success: function(result){
         //here you handle what to do after the post
      }
    });
```

For further reference on how to use jquery go to: [This link](http://jquery.com/) The most imortant here is the ajax called which is foinf to make a post the specified utl sending the named parameters,the success function which will receive anything you write on the response on the url you are calling, and the selectors $("#name").val() which means "give me the value of the element with the id name"