# ASP.NET post part of data to another page

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms

I have following problem.

I have homepage with form , that have it's own logic , now I need to add a widget on this 
page , what the widget should do , it's to post some Data Input from user to another aspx page.

Unfortunately I've came to ASP.NET from MVC (and have no idea how to do it in asp.net), and there I'd implement it by adding another form to page , that will post to Controller I need.

In ASP.NET I can't put another form with `runat` server attribute , can anyone advise the best way of implementing this task ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, and thanks to the magic of modelbinding not much that you have to do.

[QueryString values along with id parameter in ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/02/26/querystring-values-along-with-id-parameter-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

I (and most other's i believe, rather prefer route data  (people/get/1 vs people/get?id=1)

Comment: Man , it's in MVC :) , my question is how to do this in ASP.NET