# Submitting a form withing an active Tab ASPX View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an issue with my form which contain a tab, each tab contain a form inputs, the problem is when i click 'submit' it post even values from other tabs that are not active.

code HTML in the ASPX Page :

```
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
       <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
           <input id="Submit" type="submit" onclick="noPostBack('AfficherRapport.aspx')" name="Filtrer" value="Filtrer"/> 
           <asp:HiddenField ID="position" Value='$("ul.tabs li.active").index()' runat="server"/>
           <nav>
              <ul runat="server" id="myTab" class="tabs">
                      <li class="active">
                           <a href="#tab1">enseign_site</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="">
                           <a href="#tab2">iwaHadaMakan</a>
                      </li>     
              </ul>
           </nav>

           <!-- Tab panels -->
           <div runat="server" id="myRapports" class="tabContainer">
               <div id="tab1" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
                   <input type="text" name="STAMP1" placeholder="STAMP1"/>
               </div>
               <div id="tab2" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
                   <input type="text" name="STAMP1" placeholder="STAMP1"/>
               </div>
           </div>

       </form>
   </section>
```

code Tab Jquery :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   //hiding tab content except first one
   $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();
   // adding Active class to first selected tab and show
   $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();

   // Click event on tab
   $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
           // Removing class of Active tab
           $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
           // Adding Active class to Clicked tab
           $(this).addClass("active");
           // hiding all the tab contents
           $(".tabContent").hide();
           // showing the clicked tab's content using fading effect
           $($('a', this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

           return false;
       });
   });
```

**/!** : Tabs are fulfilled in the class behid of the view if you need some extra informations, you just ask for it. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you use ASP.NET Web Forms.

To separate each tab to do its own post, you need multiple `<form>` tags.

By nature of ASP.NET Web Forms - there is only one `<form>` tag. So what you are asking can only be done using AJAX requests.

Read more here: [Can we use multiple forms in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Because all of your "tabs" are in the same `form` element.  When a `form` is submitted, *all* form elements within it are included in the submit.  Notice you have a single `form` element:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <!-- other markup -->
    <!-- Tab panels -->
    <div runat="server" id="myRapports" class="tabContainer">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
            <input type="text" name="STAMP1" placeholder="STAMP1"/>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" name="STAMP1" placeholder="STAMP1"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you want separate form posts, you need separate `form` tags.  (Likely one in each "tab" in this case.)  Each one with its own form elements.  Otherwise, with a single `form` tag, you'd need to discern in server-side code which elements are relevant and which are not.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I'm going to test that ASAP and give you some feedBacks

Answer (score 0):

That works like a sharme thanks everybody.
All the three answers were right, just to highlight that in a single page we can use as many as runat="server" we want. 
thanks for all of you.