# using two forms in single web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had created a asp web-form on which another form is posted. when ever I run an error occur which state "only one form tag will be used in form application". Is there any other possible way that I could use two form on single web-form?

Comment: This is answererd [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, .NET will strip out other `form` elements, and raise an exception (as experienced) when more than one server-side referenced `form` is specified; but this is fine, usually - you can put your form parts in panels and controls and have buttons applicable only to those elements (for things like validation and whatnot) but otherwise you can differentiate on the server-side.

Comment: panel also cause same exception. :(

Comment: Then you still have multiple forms on the page - you can't do this (easily/properly, with WebForms), so remove one form, have your root form, and use `Panel` and such so as I said to separate concerns.