# Hyperlink with server side code in master page

Tags: asp.net, events, master-pages, server-side

I guess this should be simple, but...

I have an asp.net master page.  In the master page I would like to add a hyperlink that should fire a server c# side event.  Now all the posts I read so far says not to use a hyperlink, but a `<asp:LinkButton>` instead.

Problem is that the `<asp:LinkButton>` should be in a `<form runat="server">` tag, but since this is on the master page, I already have a form section, like the one below, and I cannot have to form section on one form.

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

So what is the ideal plan B?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419519/paypal-form-ruins-my-asp-net-webforms-layout-how-to-solve/7518476#7518476

Comment: One thing that also works, although I believe it can't be best practice, is to move the opening <form> tag to the start of the Master doc.